# MATLAB MEX completed successfully but no .mexw64 file is created

Tags: c++, matlab, mingw, mex

While trying to compile my C++ files with the MinGW 4.9.2 compiler in MATLAB:

```
mex -largeArrayDims -O -output edtlicense LD=g++ LINKLIBS="$LINKLIBS -liphlpapi" edtlicense_mex.o edtlicense.o bigint.o ripemd128.o rsa.o getmac.o
```

I get the following output:

> Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
>   MEX completed successfully.

However, the `edtlicense.mexw64` file is not created.

Does anybody now what might cause this and how I could solve this? Is it normal that:

> Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'

appears instead of

> Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'

---

## EDIT:

@Amro, Here is the output from running the command:

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims -cxx -v -n -output edtlicense edtlicense_mex.o edtlicense.o bigint.o ripemd128.o rsa.o getmac.o -liphlpapi

... Looking for compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:\TDM-GCC-64').
... Looking for file 'C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\TDM-GCC-64\' ...Yes.

Found installed compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.

Set PATH = [...truncated...]
Set INCLUDE = C:\TDM-GCC-64\\include;
Set LIB = C:\TDM-GCC-64\\lib;;
Set MW_TARGET_ARCH = win64;
Set LIBPATH = C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\extern\lib\win64;

Error using mex
MEX cannot find library 'iphlpapi' specified with the -l option.
MEX looks for a file with one of the names:
 libiphlpapi.lib
 iphlpapi.lib
Please specify the path to this library with the -L option.
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the [`-outdir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#inputarg_option1optionN) option to `mex`?

Comment: Yes, no matter which outdir I use, no file is created. I belief it must have something to do with: LD=g++ LINKLIBS="$LINKLIBS -liphlpapi". Because similar code were this part is not included doesn't result in problems.

Comment: I am mistaken, simpler code doesn't create the .mexw64 files either.

Comment: Maybe writing permissions in the specific folder??

Comment: That's  not the case. If I run the same code with a different version of Matlab and a different compiler I don't have any problems.

Comment: @RamsesVerachtert: try the following and post the output please: `mex -largeArrayDims -cxx -v -n -output edtlicense edtlicense_mex.o edtlicense.o bigint.o ripemd128.o rsa.o getmac.o -liphlpapi` (assuming you previously configured MinGW-w64 compiler with `mex -setup C++`)

Comment: @RamsesVerachtert ok as the error message explains, the compiler couldnt find the `iphlpapi` library. You need to specify the location of the LIB file using the `-L` option, something like: `mex ... -L'C:\path\to\libs' -liphlpapi` where "C:\path\to\libs" is the directory containing the import lib file "iphlpapi.lib". Next time you rerun this, please remove the `-v -n` flags ("v" is for verbose output, and "n" is to display the commands without actually running them).

Comment: @RamsesVerachtert sorry I just realized that `iphlpapi` is a Windows SDK library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366073.aspx. So no need to specify any path using `-L` (compiler should find it by default), just link against it using `mex file.cpp -liphlpapi -lws2_32` (note the order is important, and the `-l` libraries must come last)

Comment: @RamsesVerachtert hold on, I just tried compiling a simple MEX-function using MinGW, and I think the error is coming from the `mex` command in MATLAB (before even invoking the compiler/linker). It tries to look for [lib]iphlpapi.lib file for the library, but MinGW has `libiphlpapi.a` as a static lib instead... This is a bug I would say! One way to avoid this bug: `mex -largeArrayDims file.cpp LINKLIBS="$LINKLIBS -liphlpapi -lws2_32"`

Comment: @Amro This doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately. Still no .mexw64 files are created.

Comment: @RamsesVerachtert I'm out of ideas, can you share the project you're trying to compile? I can test it myself and show how to compile it..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
mex -largeArrayDims -output edtlicense
  edtlicense_mex.o edtlicense.o bigint.o ripemd128.o rsa.o getmac.o
  LINKLIBS="$LINKLIBS -liphlpapi -lws2_32"
```

*(all in one line, I just added line breaks for easier reading).*

It seems that directly specifying libraries to link as `mex ... -lfoo -lbar` is problematic for the mex command when using MinGW... It tries to find `foo.lib` and `bar.lib` files even before invoking the compiler/linker, which may not always be available when using MinGW (it the case above, it's a static lib file called `libiphlpapi.a`).